# How to match a value to a range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to do a sort of modified vlookup. Below are two sample tables. I need value in Column F in the Table 2 to be compared with Col C in the Table 1 and find the value that best fits this criteria: Column F value  is within 5% of Column C value and return the corresponding Col B value from the Table 1. The Table 1 I actually work with has 30 rows - so a nested if, apart from being very cumbersome, is not possible. My knowledge of excel formulas does not extend beyond the lookups!

Table 1
 B  |  C
 a  |  4
 b  |   5
 c  |   6
 d  |   7
 e  |   8

Table 2
E  |    F   |G
A|  3.9|    a
B|  6.2|    c
C|  6.8|    d
D|  4.2|    a
E|  8.3|    e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(ROUND(E2,0),$C$2:$C$6))
```

[image]

Comment: I guess my sample was way simpler than what I am dealing with. The numbers that I am dealing with are salaries, so they are 5 and 6 figure numbers. I need to find the col C value that is within + or - 5% of the col F value and return the corresponding col B value. So, for instance if the value I am looking up is 45,565 and the Col C has these possible values (42300, 46500, 51100) it would need to bring me the Grade information corresponding to 46500.\

Comment: Then chnge the `0` in the round to `-2` or what ever your rounding on C is.